# Load time for a published web app is too slow

Tags: google-apps-script

The execution time for the scripts is slower. Although this much in a browser is great. 
And, The published web app's load time is highly intolerable, that contained junk ( Probably because the UI is done with UIBuilder and the spaces were taken in unicode characters or whatever ).

Two questions here.

1. For seamless responsiveness, Is that the script folks wished the complete javascript be loaded and run in the browser and there is nothing we could do about it ?
2. Any optimizing techniques we should look for.

Comment: Could you rephrase this question, possibly providing code examples to describe what your issue is? Regarding your #2, One source of guidance for optimizing google-apps-script is the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) document.

Comment: Okay by now it is sunset. (which was obvious I think). Please find it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset). It was `GUIBuilder` I was talking about. using it as wysiwyg, gets you huge amounts of code for a simple thing. And when we publish that app to the web and load it in browser, it will be fetching.. and fetching.. and fetching... and..!!

Comment: After the software in the context was sunset an year ago from now, someone downvoted this question. Okay great, I have some opposite following.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that hand rolling the html and delivering with `HtmlService` is significantly quicker than `UIService`. This obviously depends on your circumstances depending on how confident you are scripting your own validators and `onEdit` functions. But as a possible optimisation this is where I'd start.